# visual studio 2013 update 1 c++ projects incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions, incompatibility

After installation Update 1 on Visual Studio 2013 all my c++ projects have become incompatible. Solution explorer tab says: 0 projects - on Solution level and incompatible - on project level. It also says "The application is not installed". Unfort-ly, I have no 10 reputation to attach a screenshot...

How fix that?

Comment: I uninstalled update 1 and it helped me

Comment: If you try to open a project that isn't supported in Visual Studio 2013 ... a message that the project type isn't supported might appear .... To resolve this issue, open the programs and features page in the Windows Control Panel, select Visual Studio, and then choose Change, Repair. Then you can install the missing version.

From MSDN's blog, here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/01/20/visual-studio-2013-update-1.aspx